# How do I capture the selected option and pass in sending the registration form?

Tags: forms, options, select

I'm customizing the WordPress registration form, and I need to display an list of options from a select on form submission.

I was using the following code to capture the selected option of the select:

```
<option value="Medicine" id="option-1" <?php if($_POST['name_of_select']=='Medicine') {?> selected="selected" <?Php } ?>>Medicine</option>
```

Here's a jQuery code to generate the list:

```
function list(array_list) {

    $("#formOptions").html(""); //reset child options
    $(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options
        $("#formOptions").append("<option value=\""+array_list[i].value+"\">"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
    });

}
```

And the options of list:

```
var Option 1 = [
    {display: "Medicine", value: "Medicine" }];
```

Since the list is loaded according to another option previously selected.

Now I'm using jQuery to generate the list of options select field. But when user send a form, the value of the selected option does not sent. The option is sent blank.

My question is:

How do I capture the selected option and pass in sending the registration form?

I appreciate any tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way use jQery to populate the select field when you can use filter and hook into the form using PHP eg:

```
 //1. Add a new form element...
add_action('register_form','_register_form_wpa103118');
function _register_form_wpa103118 (){
    $name_of_select = ( isset( $_POST['name_of_select'] ) ) ? $_POST['name_of_select']: '';
    $options = array(
        'Medicine' => 'Medicine',
        'Option2' => 'Option2',
    );
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="name_of_select"><?php _e('First Name','mydomain') ?><br />
            <select name="name_of_select">
                <?php
                foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
                    $selected = ($value == $name_of_select)? ' selected="selected"': '';
                    echo '<option'.$selected.' value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
                }
                ?>
            </select>
    </p>
    <?php
}

//2. Add validation. In this case, we make sure first_name is required.
add_filter('registration_errors', '_registration_errors_wpa103118', 10, 3);
function _registration_errors_wpa103118 ($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['name_of_select'] ) )
        $errors->add( 'name_of_select', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must select ....') );

    return $errors;
}

//3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta. or do whatever you want with it.
add_action('user_register', '_user_register_wpa103118');
function _user_register_wpa103118 ($user_id) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['name_of_select'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'name_of_select', $_POST['name_of_select']);
}
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you Bainternet, is good tip. But, I need to display two select, and the secundary select is populated according the first option selected. For this, I used jQuery. 

The question is that, I do not get the option selected when the form is submited.